# How would i go about creating a browser using Gecko and SpiderMonkey? A FireFox eqv

Tags: firefox, browser, open-source, gecko, spidermonkey

Ive been searching for a while, but i haven’t found any good sources or documentation to “lead” me in the right direction.

What i’m essentially trying to do is that i want to create a skin/“better” FireFox inspired browser to suit my needs.

Is there any documentation i might’ve missed, or can someone attempt to assist me?